# Elasticsearch: Disable the Versioning of index document

Tags: elasticsearch

I could see the ElasticSearch versioning the index documents for every update. I would like to know if there is a way to disable these versions? I understand its a good to have functionality, but its just for exploring the tool. Also is there is any performance concerns with large number of versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Versioning doesn't mean that elasticsearch keeps every version of the document. It keeps only the latest one. Every document has by default an implicit `_version` field, that gets incremented whenever the document changes. That allows for optimistic locking if you need it. You can also have your own external versioning system if you want. Have a look at [this article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support/) that is all about versioning with elasticsearch.

This doesn't hurt performance at all, I wouldn't look into disabling it.

Comment: Precise enough :) Thanks Javanna

Comment: It hurts performance of course, because there is a version lookup before indexing document. This is horrible if you have many Lucene segments and don't use default ES id.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable versioning.
But the ES server will use versioning only if you specify 
`?version=[version_number]` or `?retry_on_conflict=[retry_times]`

If you don't use one of these 2 params, ES server will not do version check and conflict check, this is another way of "disable versioning".